# Do any Ubuntu-based distributions ship with Unity?

Tags: unity

I like distributions like Mint and Pinguy because they include most stuff I want to install out of the box. Are there any such Ubuntu spin-offs that use Unity by default?

Comment: The normal java (sun-java-6) will be removed from any Linux machine soon(ish). Ubuntu uses OpenJDK as default but all others will most likely have to remove it too since Oracle changed the license making it non-free.

Comment: OP, You know this was an over blown exaggeration? you can still have JAVA support, you can still install JAVA from the Oracle site, you have OpenJDK there is no Need for a spin off with Unity nor anything that drastic. As i sense that was your concern, not having Java anymore thus you couldn't use Ubuntu because of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sabily**

http://www.sabily.org

It is an Islamic Linux Distribution based on Ubuntu...... come with Unity & Gnome-Shell, have Java & Codecs installed by default........ also available in 64 bit Version.

Answer (score 4):

What would be the need of an Ubuntu spin off with unity if Ubuntu 11.10 come shipped with unity by default? Of course, you can install gnome, and personlize it at the max, since this is Linux, but there is no need to make a spinoff for something that is already included in the OS by default ^^

Comment: And then install [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) for almost everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Released 24/02/2012 is [DreamStudio](http://dream.dickmacinnis.com/forum/node/833)

[image]

---

[ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unity) has the ability to install the Unity-Shell - according to their wiki - this ability is unsupported by their developers but they include two repositories for the ArchLinux user to install from.

Fedora had mentioned there was a possibility of a Unity shell - but that development seems to have gone quiet.

The LinuxMint community also have the ability to install the Unity Shell:

[image]

Comment: My personal experience has been that Unity doesn't seem to work too well on Linux Mint; and similarly, the only Mate desktop worth having is Linux Mint's.